# I'm making a python script that strips whitespace off of the end of lines, but it is only working on the first line

Tags: python, for-loop, text-files, whitespace

Like I said in the title, my script only seems to work on the first line.
Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys



def main():
  a = sys.argv[1]
  f = open(a,'r')
  lines = f.readlines()
  w = 0
  for line in lines:
    spot = 0
    cp = line
    for char in reversed(cp):
      x = -1
      if char == ' ':
        del line[x]
        w += 0
      if char != '\n' or char != ' ':
        lines[spot] = line
        spot += 1
        break
      x += 1
  f.close()
  f = open(a,'w')
  f.writelines(lines)
  print("White Space deleted: "+str(w))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I'm not too experienced when it comes to loops.

Comment: `string.rstrip()` will trim white space off the end of a string.

Comment: You do know Python has a `str.rstrip()` method, right? It removes whitespace from the end of lines..

Comment: `w += 0` is probably not what you wanted..

Comment: Oh yeah, but that just counts how many spaces have been deleted @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Awalrod: So you count to 0 every time.

Comment: Please remember: Python has [batteries included](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/stdlib.html#batteries-included).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script do the same thing as your program, more compactly:

```
import fileinput

deleted = 0
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    stripped = line.rstrip()
    deleted += len(line) - len(stripped) + 1  # don't count the newline
    print(stripped)

print("Whitespace deleted: {}".format(deleted))
```

Here [`str.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) removes *all* whitespace from the end of a line (newlines, spaces and tabs).

The [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) takes care of handling `sys.argv` for you, opening files one by one if you name more than one file.

Using `print()` will add the newline back on to the end of the stripped lines.

Comment: If somebody else is wondering: "Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument inplace=1 is passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently). This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file in place."

Comment: This works, but why doesn't `print(line.rstrip())` output to the terminal? Also, what does the `inplace=True` mean.

Comment: @Awalrod: the `fileinput.input(inplace=True)` call redirects `sys.stdout` to the output file. Printing then writes to the replacement file instead. This is a feature of that module. `inplace=True` enables that feature.

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip()` is probably what you want to use to achieve this.

```
>>> 'Here is my string       '.rstrip()
'Here is my string'
```

A more compact way to iterate backwards over stings is

```
>>> for c in 'Thing'[::-1]:
        print(c)


g
n
i
h
T
```

`[::-1]` is slice notation. SLice notaion can be represented as  `[start:stop:step]`. In my example a `-1` for the step means it will step form the back by one index. `[x:y:z]` will start at index `x` stop at `y-1` and go forward by `z` places each step.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `rstrip`:

```
f = open(a,'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open(a,'w')
for line in lines:
    f.write(line.rstrip()+'\n')
f.close()
```